# Called the UISlider with tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, tags, uislider

I am using the three UISlider in a view controller and I want to call the same function for all the sliders. Here is my code

```
[yourWeightSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; 
    [physicalActivitySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

These two sliders calling the same method "sliderValueChange".How I separate which slider is called. I don't know how to use tag. I am new in iOS. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code snip

*First add a tag to each slider*

```
yourWeightSlider.tag = 100
physicalActivitySlider.tag = 200
```

*get the tag value and decide todo*

```
-(void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {

    int tag = sender.tag;
}
```